# using JSON data in client side javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

Im fairly new to node.js and express. My question is how to correctly retrieve json data in a client side javascript file since im getting a 404 code about the .json file not being found.

my file structure is a generic express structure and the .json file is in the nodeapp folder right below the package.json file and app.js. Im trying to access this file from a javascript file that is saved in `public/javascripts` folder but can seem to get around it. here is the function im trying to implement in the .js file:

```
function getJSONData(){
    var json;
    $.getJSON('/public/web_text.json', function(data){

        json = data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

You need to setup static files in express, and you do it like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

You then can call it from your client (without the **public** prefix):

```
$.getJSON('/javascript/web_text.json', function(data){});
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

---

### Option 2

Your other option is to send it via `sendFile` http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile:

```
app.get('/public/web_text.json', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/my_json_file.json');
});
```

Then in your client you can call it like this:

```
$.getJSON('/public/web_text.json', function(data){})
```

Comment: still same error.... my web_text.json file is not saved under the public/javascripts file! it is saved in the main app folder where the package.json and app.js is located

Comment: when i reload the browser and call the function in the client side js file i get an error saying that the variable app was not defined...

Comment: that is your server side code, it needs to go there

Comment: so you're saying option 2 code must go in my app.js file?

Comment: option 1 and/or option 2 must go in your app.js file, aka the file loaded via `node`